# Prevent POST requests generated externally

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to prevent POSTs that aren't being generated from the server itself? (NGINX)

Something in the server config file along the lines of the following, but only if the POST is from the same server:

```
# add_header Allow "POST" always;
if ( $request_method !~ ^(POST)$ ) {
    return 403;
}
```

Comment: The only way you could tell is by referrer, if the client is not blocking the referrer for privacy.

Comment: @DerfK ...and referrers are fairly easily spoofed, so not ideal.

Comment: the only other way to do this is at the application level, for instance, adding a [CSRF token](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_\(CSRF\)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Synchronizer_.28CSRF.29_Tokens).  Nginx cannot know how the user's browser decided to make the request it did, other than by what the user's browser sends.